# Oracle database where clause

Tags: join, oracle11g

I have the following db with tables and and i do try to query them:
Retrieve the names, addresses, and number of books checked out for all borrowers who have more than five books checked out.
I have created the query

```
select name, Address
from BORROWER
where BOOK_LOANS.BookId >= 5;
```

Seems i need a join for the tables, i'm stuck here, Can I please get help?

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK ( 
  BookId CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  Title VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PublisherName VARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (BookId),
  FOREIGN KEY (PublisherName) REFERENCES PUBLISHER (PublisherName) 
);

CREATE TABLE BOOK_AUTHORS ( 
  BookId CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  AuthorName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (BookId, AuthorName),
  FOREIGN KEY (BookId) REFERENCES BOOK (BookId)
  ON DELETE CASCADE 
);

// PublisherName was added, as it was referenced by another 
// table but did not exist as an attribute.

CREATE TABLE PUBLISHER ( 
  PublisherName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  Address VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  Phone CHAR(12),
  PRIMARY KEY (PublisherName) 
);

CREATE TABLE BOOK_COPIES ( 
  BookId CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  BranchId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  No_Of_Copies INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (BookId, BranchId),
  FOREIGN KEY (BookId) REFERENCES BOOK (BookId)
  ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (BranchId) REFERENCES BRANCH (BranchId)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE BORROWER ( 
  CardNo INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  Address VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  Phone CHAR(12),
  PRIMARY KEY (CardNo) 
);

CREATE TABLE BOOK_LOANS ( 
  CardNo INTEGER NOT NULL,
  BookId CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  BranchId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  DateOut DATE NOT NULL,
  DueDate DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (CardNo, BookId, BranchId),
  FOREIGN KEY (CardNo) REFERENCES BORROWER (CardNo)
  ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (BranchId) REFERENCES BRANCH (BranchId)
  ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (BookId) REFERENCES BOOK (BookId)
  ON DELETE SET NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE BRANCH ( 
  BranchId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  BranchName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  Address VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (BranchId) 
);
```

Comment: Yes you need a join. Fortunately they are pretty well documented. What have you tried?

Comment: You tag MySQL but say Oracle. Which one do you mean?

Comment: MySQL is also Oracle. ;-) Nevertheless, this is your third question where some serious re-tagging was needed and no effort was shown to try and solve the problem yourself. Therefor I've downvoted your question. Please search and attempt to solve the problem yourself first. If you are stock on an actual attempt, we are here to help. Also, please put effort in your questions too. It is *your* problem that needs solving.

Comment: Well, Oracle owned, but it's SQL is quite different from Oracles. So I still suggest correct tags.

Comment: @GolezTrol I edited the question and removed the tags, I will be more careful in future . Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do indeed need a join that connects the `BORROWER` table with the `BOOK_LOANS` table. The join should be on the shared key (which is `CardNO`).

To count the number of books borrowed you use the `COUNT()` aggregate function, and you combine that with a `GROUP BY` clause that partition your data in to groups based on the unique combination of `CardNo, Name, Address`.

Now you have a count of books borrowed for each CardNo.

Finally you apply the `HAVING` clause to filter the groups to only include those groups that have a count of five or more books borrowed.

```
SELECT b.Name, b.Address, COUNT(*) AS BookCount
FROM BORROWER b
JOIN BOOK_LOANS bl ON b.CardNo = bl.CardNo
GROUP BY b.CardNO, b.Name, b.Address
HAVING COUNT(bl.BookID) >= 5
```

Comment: Thank you!!! great explanation and I'm looking on HAVING Clause now. I was doing by count and ORDER BY